# WPF client for class library : how to notify error to UI?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, notifications

I'm new to WPF and I'm working on a project that will have the following components : a WCF server class library, a WCF client class library, a WPF client UI and a WPF server UI.

I have a method in WCF client that add a user to a collection in the client and then register this user in the server. The method checks that user doesn't already exist locally then register in on the server that throws a FaultException if the user already exist on it.

How can I notify the client that operation doesn't succeed and that he must choose an other name? Throwing an exception? Adding code in ViewModel to check if user exists before calling add method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best option is to check from the ViewModel on the server if the user already exists, if so, show a message on the UI.

Exceptions must be used for unexpected situations, and this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways. Take a moment to learn ValidationRules. This should help with that.

[How to disable a Button on TextBox ValidationErrors in WPF](http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/02/03/how-to-disable-a-button-on-textbox-validationerrors-in-wpf/)

Howevever, you could do the same thing without a ValidationRule. Just have some error text that has Visibility bound to a bool in the ViewModel. Of course the error text would only be Visibile if user already exists.

Once you have looked at those two  options, you should know which on is best for your project.